# "What time do you swim?" vs "What time do you go swimming?"

Tags: present-tense, present-progressive

What's the difference?
The English curriculum is really weird in Japan, which is why the country is ranked very low in ESL.

Comment: I am puzzled as to how the English curriculum in Japan is connected to the question in the title!

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @ Akinyele. Please check out the [help] to learn how to get the best out of this site. I suggest that you edit your question to include what research your have done, and explain what you don't understand. And remove the superfluous material about Japan's English curriculum.

Comment: There is really very little difference between these.

Comment: Are you saying you're studying English in Japan and didn't receive an accurate explanation of the above example? I live in Tokyo, so I'm curious. I'm primarily bothered by their pronunciation.

Comment: Mentioning English teaching in Japan is relevant. It can give insight into why the question is being asked and what kind of answer is wanted. Whether research needs to be demonstrated or whether the question would better be asked at [English Language Learners SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com) are other issues.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a question in a textbook or for a class, then the answer they want is probably that

> *do swim*
>  is written in the simple present tense and means regularly, always, according to a schedule
>
> *do go swimming*
>  is written in the present continuous tense and refers to an "arrangement" to swim, probably in the near future.

The above are simplifications or "rules of thumb" often used to teach ESL learners about verb forms for referring to the future. Unfortunately, they often cause much confusion, with fuzzy and artificial distinctions made, for example, between the "planned" vs. the "arranged" future.

In reality, most people often use the above phrases somewhat interchangeably. We are more likely to mean what I have written above, but we often use context instead to indicate any difference, when it matters. We might add something like "When do you go swimming on Wednesdays?" "When do you swim today?" This is quite often true among most American English speakers. British and other groups may be more likely to regard the above as "rules", to follow them more strictly, and to regard different uses as mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Most people, if asked, would say they do (or don't) **like to go swimming**.  Saying simply that you **like to swim** sounds rather grand and formal (which, of course, may be the case).

So, although the questions are essentially very similar '...**do you swim**?' sounds less natural/everyday than '...**do you go swimming**?'

Comment: There is no question about "like".

Comment: No, indeed, there isn't.  And clearly it is distracting.  My bad.  The essence of my answer to the question is contained in my second para.  The first para was intended to show how, even in the context of everyday speech ('like to') the use of the present simple sounds rather grand and formal (which is not, probably, what the speaker would like to be)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many cases in (American) English where a slight nuance in the way things are phrased will change the meaning. While either of these sentences would be understood, using them in the wrong context would probably identify you as a non-native speaker - which is no big deal in the US, as we are a land of immigrants, and our ears are trained to understand many variations of our language. That being said:

*"When do you swim?"* is a question to ask someone whom you know swims regularly - as if it is part of a training or health routine. (You are asking about their schedule.)

*"When do you go swimming?* has a more recreational connotation - you might ask it of someone who has access to a pool, or someone who spends all day baking in the sun on the beach. (You are asking about their habits.)